install Unity desktop
Is there any danger installing the Unity desktop instead of using GNOME? Is it less secure? Is it fully compatible with Snap and all Ubuntu applications? I prefer the look of Unity over GNOME.

Ubuntu Unity has been an official flavor for some time, so it's as useful as any other Ubuntu flavor. It'll run all Ubuntu apps, equally as all Ubuntu flavors will, as the Ubuntu Unity differs only that it's built using a different seed file, but that build of ISO is done by the Ubuntu infrastructure/builders as Ubuntu Desktop and all other flavors.
Like all flavors though, the packages that are used include many from universe which do not get the checks performed by the Ubuntu Security Team, but otherwise procedures are the same (changes still go through the same SRU process etc).
I'm using a Ubuntu Desktop flavor desktop currently, and I'm not worried about the differences in using flavors and the GNOME Desktop used by Ubuntu Desktop (where packages included on install media were all checked by the Ubuntu Security team), but some corporate environments do want the added security of avoiding the universe repository.
You can add additional checks & fixes to universe via Ubuntu Pro, but whilst I've not looked, I wouldn't expect any changes specific to the Unity Desktop.

Answered as I got too long for a comment (once again)... the idea of danger however to me is opinion, so I've limited to the one difference I see in relation to lack of security checks on universe or community packages that I see between flavor packages & main ISO used packages from Ubuntu Desktop/Server..

If there is a duplicate link between flavors and Ubuntu Desktop I didn't find it sorry; but will happily flag this question as seeking off-topic opinion or duplicate...

Thanks for providing the explanation about what "flavors" are. From the GNOME desktop, the way to install it its: sudo apt install ubuntu-unity-desktop. Correct?

That is how I'd install it @Apollo18, my own system I'm using now runs Ubuntu oracular, on which I've installed a number of desktops including ubuntu-desktop (GNOME), xubuntu-desktop (Xfce) ... though I started with a Lubuntu install (of which I'm using LXQt currently).... FYI:  If you explore the seed file I provided a link to, you'll note ubuntu-unity-desktop is mentioned [I think] rather prominently.
